# Where is the settings option to Divert or block incoming calls

Tags: settings, calls, call-screening

Where can I find the option to divert and block incoming calls on my mobile.
I was unable to find it. It is available on all mobiles. Where is it in Android?

- Android version: **5.0 Lollipop**
- Mobile manufacturer: **Micromax**

Comment: That might depend on your device and Android version – so could you please [edit] your question and include those details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open your call button, tap the 3 dots in search bar top right, then settings and you have both.